# Understanding Application insights error log for socket exceptions

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, socketexception

I am struggling with `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException` because of some dependencies error.
Below are the details.

I can't understand what it means.

**Path: http://seq/api/events/raw**

Below is screen shot of details.

[image: az]

Comment: This looks like your app is calling that endpoint?

Comment: Can you give more details, like the code of your function app?